# Post method prevents the page to load

Tags: php, html

I have created a page called profile.php that gets a value from mainpage.php, by using "get" method. But, If the value that was sent from mainpage.php is empty or wrong, the page redirects to the mainpage.php. However, I used "post" method in profile.php that allows users to post something in profile.php. So that If the user submits something, profile.php reloads and reloading profile.php makes the variable, that i get from mainpage, empty and directs the page to mainpage.php unwillingly.How can i fix it? Codes;

```
$another_user = $_GET['username'];//gets a value from mainpage.php
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$another_user."'");
$sent = mysql_fetch_array($check);
if(!$sent)
{
header('Location: mainpage.php');
    exit();
}

//some codes around here

<form action="profile.php" method="post">
Commet: <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder = "comments?"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['comment'])&&!($_POST['comment']=""))
{
$writing = $_POST['comment'];
echo $writing;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you realise you're missing a " at the end of your SQL query? Also, it'd be more helpful to see the whole file, not just this snippet.

Comment: I disagree, Prisoner. His code snippet shows enough to get his problem. But yes, you are missing a " as I noted in my answer.

Comment: Yes, i realized that:(But actually, i made it accidently while translating my codes into english to make more sense. Codes are fine in terms of syntax, but except the problem that mentioned in the question:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with you have a syntax error in your second line, as the colors show you already. So change it into:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$another_user."')";
```

There are many solutions to your problem. One of them could be to verify which page the user is coming from. If this is `mainpage.php` you can verify the `username` and if this is `profile.php` you should check the `comment` variable.

You can make use of the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable to check which is the referer. So something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://www.domain.com/mainpage.php") {
   //do your username check
}
else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://www.domain.com/profile.php") {
   //do your comment check
}
```

Another and maybe easier way would be to make sure that your `$_POST['comment']` has not been set when dealing with the `username`.. Like this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['comment'])) {
    $another_user = $_GET['username'];//gets a value from mainpage.php
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$another_user."'");
    $sent = mysql_fetch_array($check);
    if(!$sent) {
        header('Location: mainpage.php');
        exit();
    }
}
else {
    //...
}
```